# Have You Used Node.js In A Production Environment?

Tags: javascript

This question goes out to anyone that's used or tried to use node.js in a serious project. How stable is it? What did you use it for? How robust is it?

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I haven't used it in production but I know several companies already did.
For example, [GitHub uses Node.js](http://github.com/blog/678-meet-nodeload-the-new-download-server) to power the download server.

Answer (score 3):

The bottom of [the index page of the node.js wiki on github](http://github.com/ry/node/wiki) lists a number of companies that are using node.js, some apparently for live and public applications which would generally be considered to be "in production".

Comment: Could you add a link please?

Comment: Sorry I thought I'd done that. I've edited the post to correctly add the link.